# Collision point detection and location between two objects in Java game(LWJGL)

Tags: java, collision-detection, lwjgl, pong, collision

as the typical "Hello World" for game development I decided to make the pong game since I am learning to use LWJGL.

As of now, I already have both my entities ready (bat and ball), but the ball just runs back and forth on the x-axis. I obviously want it to hit the bat and run on different angles depending on how it was hit. The issue is I can detect the collision between both entities, but I have no idea how to tell at what point did the ball collide with the bat. Is there a specific algorithm, function or even a second library that can help me?

Thank you very much!

Edit: as requested, this is the code for the current collision detection that I have

```
    if(ball.getX()<=bat.getX()+bat.getWidth() && ball.getX() >= bat.getX() && 
        ball.getY()>=bat.getY() && ball.getY()<=bat.getY()+bat.getHeights()){
        //for now, the code in here just makes the ball go the opposite direction
    }
```

Comment: Post the code you have written so far.

Comment: @nwk just added the relevant code that I am currently using. It is just that simple if statement.

Answer (score 0):

How are you detecting collisions?  I would think that if you are able to detect collisions, it would be because you know the position of the ball and the bat.

Edit:

OK, I have not done this exact type of program before, if it is a Hello World program, for simplicity's sake you may want to just have the bat and the ball just have a point location and the if statement would be

```
if(ball.getX() == bat.getX() && ball.getY() == bat.getY()){
    //for now, the code in here just makes the ball go the opposite direction
}
```

If you really want a bat with a width, you could do something like

```
double xDist = ball.getX() - bat.getX();
double yDist = ball.getY() - bat.getY();
if(xDist * xDist + yDist * yDist <= BAT_WIDTH * BAT_WIDTH) {
    //use trigonometry to find the angle between the ball and the mid point of the bat, and then find the point on the bat's surface that corresponds to that angle
}
```

Comment: It is a very simple if statement that gets the object's coordinates. I added it to my question so you can see.